# PHP script thrown Error #1054 in MySQL when column is exist

Tags: php, mysql

My query:

```
$name    = $vm_product->product_name;

$columns = array('cart_id', 'product_id', 'quantity', 'price', 'name');
$values  = array($cart_id, $product_id, $quantity, $price, $name);

$query
           ->insert($db->quoteName('#__products'))
           ->columns($db->quoteName($columns))
           ->values(implode(',', $values));

$db->setQuery($query);
$db->execute();
```

If `$name` is numbers only, as example `$name = 100`, then everything is OK.

But if `$name` is a string, as an example `$name = "Cable"`, an error is thrown:

> 1054 - Unknown column 'Cable' in 'field list'

Why #1054? `"Cable"` is not a column!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because when you implode, your values becomes `WHERE column_name IN (Cable,Another string,Some other value)` and that is syntax error because of missing quotes around string literals (when there is no spaces in strings, mysql assumes its names of columns).

Use `->values("'" . implode("','", $values) . "'")`, or consult your used code base documentation how to properly and securely generate WHERE IN condition